# Java Image coordinates (0,0) being in the bottom right corner

Tags: java, image-processing

I have this weird problem that when I interact with an image, for example

```
img.getRGB(imgx, imgy);
```

or

```
g.drawImage(img, x, y, x+16,y+16, imgx, imgy, imgx+16, imgy+16);
```

The coordinate system for the image (imgx, imgy) is centered around the bottom right corner.

```
public class Terrain {

private final TerrainTile[][] terrainArray;

public Terrain(BufferedImage img) {

    System.out.println("X: " + img.getWidth() + " Y: " + img.getHeight());
    terrainArray = new TerrainTile[img.getWidth()][img.getHeight()];

    for (int x = 0; x < img.getWidth(); x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < img.getHeight(); y++,) {
            System.out.println("X: " + x + " Y: " + y + " Color: " + img.getRGB(x, y));
            fillTerrain(x, y, img.getRGB(x, y));
        }
    }

}

private void fillTerrain(int x, int y, int color) {
    switch (color) {
    case 0xFF0000FF: // BLUE
        terrainArray[x][y] = TerrainTile.WATER;
        break;
    case 0xFF00FF00: // GREEN
        terrainArray[x][y] = TerrainTile.GRASSLAND;
        break;
    case 0xFF007F00: // DARK GREEN
        terrainArray[x][y] = TerrainTile.FORREST;
        break;
    case 0xFF666666: // GREY
        terrainArray[x][y] = TerrainTile.HILL;
        break;
    default: // BLANK
        terrainArray[x][y] = TerrainTile.BLANK;
        break;
    }
}
```

With that the map of game I "scan in" from an image always is turned 180°
when I print it out

```
    public void printTerrain() {
    for (int x = 0; x < terrainArray.length; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < terrainArray[0].length; y++) {
            System.out.print(getTileID(x, y) + ", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Is this normal, and what is the best methode to prevent this?

Comment: Can you provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code i believe you are rotating the graphics "g" which might be causing this to occur. It would be nice to have an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to figure out whats wrong.

Maybe check what `img.getRGB(16,16)` gives you and you might find whats wrong in your code.

Comment: I found my error. For the printTerrain methode I made the mistake to print out columns not rows of the array.